# LAPACK routine ZGEEV - gives wrong eigenvalues

Tags: fortran90, lapack

I wrote the following program in fortran that uses a lapack subroutine called [ZGEEV](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/index.htm#GUID-9753DBC0-04D2-40EA-B1BD-4C83D1FD8C43.htm). The idea was to see how  the eigenvalues of the matrix [image: matrix to diagonalised]  change as k goes from real to complex. Analytically, the answers should be 2 and 0, whether k is complex or not. But I obtain a plot that shows a lot variation.
Especially for real k, the plot looks like this -
[image: Plot for eigenvalues vs k]
Here is the code i wrote -

```
           program main
             implicit none
       !**********************************************                 
             complex(8) :: k,mat(2,2)
             complex(8) :: eigenvals(2)
             real(8), parameter    :: kmax = 2.d0 
             real(8), parameter    :: dk = 1.d-1 
             real(8)               :: kr,ki
       !**********************************************
             kr=-kmax
             do while (kr.le.kmax)
                ki= -1.d-3
                do while (ki.le.1.d-3)
                   k=cmplx(kr,ki)
                   call init_mat(k,mat)
                   call diagonalize(mat,eigenvals)
                   print*, real(k), real(eigenvals(2)),aimag(eigenvals(2))
                   ki=ki+1.d-4
                end do
                kr=kr+dk
             end do
           end program main





           subroutine init_mat(k,mat)
             implicit none
             complex(8),intent(in) :: k
             complex(8),intent(out):: mat(2,2)
             complex(8),parameter  :: di=(0.d0,1.d0)
             complex(8),parameter  :: d1=(1.d0,0.d0)
        !**********************************************
             mat(1,1) = d1 
             mat(1,2) = exp(di*k)
             mat(2,1) = exp(di*k) 
             mat(2,2) = d1 
             return
           end subroutine init_mat

           subroutine diagonalize(mat,eigenvals)
             implicit none
             complex(8),intent(in) :: mat(2,2)
             complex(8),intent(out):: eigenvals(2)
             complex(8)            :: vl(2,2),vr(2,2)
             complex(8),allocatable:: work(:)
             integer(4)            :: lwork
             complex(8)            :: rwork(4)
             complex(8)            :: mat2(2,2)
             integer(4)            :: info
        !**********************************************
             mat2(:,:) = mat(:,:)
             allocate(work(6))
             call zgeev('N', 'N', 2, mat2, 2, eigenvals, vl, 2, vr, 2, work, -1, rwork, info)
             lwork = work(1)
             deallocate(work)
             allocate(work(lwork))
             call zgeev('V', 'V', 2, mat2, 2, eigenvals, vl, 2, vr, 2, work, lwork, rwork, info)
             if (info.ne.0) print*, info
             stop 'diagonalize failed'
           end subroutine diagonalize
```

Any lazy theorizing as to the causes of this aberration is welcome in the comments!

PS: i wrote up a similar code in python and there the eigenvalues are two constant lines at y=2 and y=0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in subroutine init_mat(k,mat)

mat(1,2) = exp(di*k)
and
mat(2,1) = exp(di*k)

But one of them, e.g., mat(2,1) should = exp(-di*k)

Although your math project calls for a matrix with e^ik and e^-ik on the off-diagonals, the code shown instead is creating a matrix with e^ik on both off-diagonals.  The matrix actually coded has complex eigenvalues, so the subroutines for finding eigenvalues may be working correctly and the input as shown has a mis-specification.

So what are the eigenvalues of [[1, e^ik], [e^ik, 1]]?

Well, the trace is still 2, so the eigenvalues sum to 2.

And the determinant is 1-e^(2ik), so the product is complex.

This suggests that the eigenvalues of the matrix actually input are complex conjugates that sum to 2.  By inspection, the eigenvalues seem to be 1 +/- e^ik